# Jackson deserialize "" as an empty list

Tags: json, spring, jackson, deserialization

I have a JSON string that marks empty lists as `""` instead of `[]`. So for example, if I have an object with no children, I'll receive a string like this:

```
{"id":13, "children":""}
```

I'd like to deserialize that to a Parent class, with children properly set to an empty list of children.

```
public class Parent {

    private Long id;
    private List<Child> children;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

For the above JSON string, I'd like an object that will have its `id` set to `13`, and the `children` set to a `new ArrayList<Child>()`

```
Parent
    id <- 13
    children <- new ArrayList<Child>()
```

I would know how to use an annotation for the entire class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ParentDeserializer.class)
public class Parent { 
    ...
}
```

and then

```
public class ParentDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Parent> {
    public Parent deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to solve a general problem of instantiating Lists properly from `""` strings:

```
public class Parent {
    ...
    // Can I get something like this?
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyArrayDeserializer<Child>.class) 
    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

Can I get something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of options; first, you want to enable `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT':

```
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

so that empty String becomes null. And if you want it to get converted to actual empty List, override setter:

```
public void setChildren(List<Child> c) {
    if (c == null) {
       children = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
       chidlren = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for collections? https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/91 marked as open is saying that it only works for single objects.

Comment: It does work -- I assumed it did not, based on a user report, but it does and there are unit tests for it. 'OBJECT' here means any Java object.

Comment: I can confirm it works. I'm still not comfortable with explicit instantiations of empty lists (I was hoping that a deserializer could do that for me in a generic way), but it will have to do. Thank you!

Comment: Understood. Things get problematic as there are so many odd things some languages and libraries do (mostly scripting ones like Perl, JS), hard to find simple and generic handling -- oftentimes incompatible data is error, and it's not good to hide errors either.

Comment: @ipavlic Problem is that as name implies, empty String becomes `null`, not other type of object