# How to handle empty or null values when converting json string to pojo using jackson wtih java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Below is the json response i am converting to pojo using jackson -

```
{
    paymentType": [
        {
            "Monthly": ["Monthly", "Monthly"],
            "Prepaid": ["Prepaid", "Prepaid"]
        },
        ""
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
String rspString = "{\"paymentType\": [{\"Monthly\": [\"Monthly\",\"Monthly\"],\"Prepaid\": [\"Prepaid\",\"Prepaid\"]},\"\"]}";

JsonUtil jsonUtil = new JsonUtil();
PaymentTypeResponse PaymentTypeRsp = new PaymentTypeResponse();
PaymentTypeRsp = (PaymentTypeResponse) jsonUtil.Json2Object(rspString, PaymentTypeRsp);
System.out.println(PaymentTypeRsp.getPaymentType().size());
```

I am getting the below exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class
>   com.test.sample.PaymentTypeRespons] from String value (''); no
>   single-String constructor/factory method

There is a blank value in the response, how to handle those values while converting to pojo?

In the same way if null is there how to handle this case?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the class:

```
public class PaymentType 
{
    @JsonProperty("Monthly")
    public List<String> monthly;
    @JsonProperty("Prepaid")
    public List<String> prepaid;

     //getter and setters
}

public PaymentTypeResponse 
{
    @JsonProperty("paymentType")
    public List<PaymentType> paymentType;

    //setters and Getters
}
```

Comment: please add PaymentTypeResponse  class

Answer (score 1):

If you're only receiving either `null` or the empty string instead of a JSON object that correctly represents your `PaymentType` class, it's enough to set the following deserialization feature in the `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

Now, the empty string will be coerced to `null`, and you won't have this problem any more.

---

A more general approach (though more complex to handle) would be to add a constructor that accepts a `String` argument to your `PaymentType` class:

```
public PaymentType() {
}

public PaymentType(String json) {
    // parse the json string here and initialize members
}
```

Within the constructor that receives a `String` argument, you can parse the string as you want.

Note that you also need to add the no-args constructor, so that Jackson can deserialize from valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is incorrect according to your pojo classes. In your json, the 3rd element inside "paymentType" array is an empty string which should be an array or simply null.

Change your json from this -

```
{
    "paymentType": [{
        "Monthly": ["Monthly", "Monthly"],
        "Prepaid": ["Prepaid", "Prepaid"]
    }, ""]
}
```

to this -

```
{
    "paymentType": [{
        "Monthly": ["Monthly", "Monthly"],
        "Prepaid": ["Prepaid", "Prepaid"]
    }]
}
```

Json string -

```
 String rspString = "{\"paymentType\": [{\"Monthly\": [\"Monthly\",\"Monthly\"],\"Prepaid\": [\"Prepaid\",\"Prepaid\"]},null]}";
```

OR this -

```
{
    "paymentType": [{
        "Monthly": ["Monthly", "Monthly"],
        "Prepaid": ["Prepaid", "Prepaid"]
    }, null]
}
```

Json string -

```
String rspString = "{\"paymentType\": [{\"Monthly\": [\"Monthly\",\"Monthly\"],\"Prepaid\": [\"Prepaid\",\"Prepaid\"]}]}";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i cannot change the json it is developed as it is which holds empty value. based on that json i have written the  class . i could not write the 3rd as it holds  empty value ,

Comment: for this you have to write your own custom deserializer, this might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933394/jackson-deserialize-as-an-empty-list