# How to define a generic list deserializer through annotations with Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Let's say I have an object which has list properties:

```
public class Citizen {
    name
    List<Tickets> tickets
    List<Fines> fines
}
```

I'd like to define a generic custom deserializer for lists through annotations:

```
public class Citizen {
    ...
    @JsonDeserializer(MyListDeserializer<Tickets>) // <-- generic deserializer
    public void setTickets(List<Tickets> tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }

    @JsonDeserializer(MyListDeserializer<Fines>) // <-- how can I do that? 
    public void setFines(List<Fines> fines) {
        this.fines = fines;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to create a "generic" deserializer — one that would be able to deserialize both types of lists, similar to [ContextualDeserializer for mapping JSON to different types of maps with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704992/contextualdeserializer-for-mapping-json-to-different-types-of-maps-with-jackson/6714275).

The final purpose is to implement custom deserializing logic in `MyListDeserializer` to deserialize empty strings `""` as empty lists, but I'd like to know about a general approach, not just for empty strings.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without subclassing your generic deserialiser so it has a solid type. Otherwise your deserialiser will not be aware of what type it is meant to be returning. You may be interested in the `contentAs` attribute of the `@JsonDeserialze` annotation.

Comment: How about explaining what exactly you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to customize handling of the List itself, or that of values? Solution differs, and you can use default handling for one, both or neither.

Comment: @StaxMan My final goal is something similar to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933394/jackson-deserialize-as-an-empty-list. I wanted to simplify that question, but perhaps now there isn't enough information. I'll try and edit the question.

Comment: @Dunes I saw something similar for maps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704992/contextualdeserializer-for-mapping-json-to-different-types-of-maps-with-jackson/6714275, so I thought it might be possible.

Comment: Ok, so you do want to change handling of actual Collection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify the deserializer class with which to deserialize the elements of the list 
with the `contentUsing` attribute of the `@JsonDeserializer` annotation.

```
public class Citizen {
    ...
    @JsonDeserializer(contentUsing=MyListDeserializer.class) 
    public void setTickets(List<Tickets> tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }
}
```

Make your deserializer extend `JsonDeserializer<BaseClass>` and have a attribute in the BaseClass that stores the actual type of the concrete class.

```
abstract class BaseTickets {
    String ticketType;
    public String getTicketType()
}

public class MyListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BaseTickets> {

    @Override
    public BaseTickets deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = node.getElements();
        for (; elements.hasNext();) {
            String type = (String) elements.next().get("ticketType");

            if (type.equals()){
               //create concrete type here
            }
        }
     }
```

Or if you want a single deserializer for all List types with no common base class, then use the `using` attribute, have `MyListDeserializer` extend `JsonDeserialize<Object>`. For determining the type of list element you would have to write a custom serializer that adds the type information to the list which can then be used in the generic deserializer.

```
public class Citizen {
    ...
    @JsonDeserializer(using=MyListDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerializer(using=MyListSerializer.class) 
    public void setTickets(List<Tickets> tickets) {
        this.tickets = tickets;
    }
}

public class MyListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object list, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        String type = getListType(list);
        jgen.writeStringField("listType", type);
        jgen.writeObjectField("list", list)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd then have to make one for each type of list I'd have. Can it be generic?

Comment: If you wanted to customize handling of type `Tickets`, you would use property "contentUsing" instead of "using".

Comment: The second case is what I'm after. How would a custom type-adding deserializer look like? I was hoping to find something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704992/contextualdeserializer-for-mapping-json-to-different-types-of-maps-with-jackson/6714275

Comment: well if it works for map then you can replace Map<String, ?> with List<?> & mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, targetType)) with mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionLikeType(List.class,targetType)) in the example.

Comment: The annotation is called `@JsonDeserialize` (https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html)