# Create a generic Jackson JSON Deserializer on Java

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, deserialization

### Problem

Some of my JSON objects has a property name "id", so I'd like to create a generic deserializer that call the specific method to retrieve a POJO from the database. Also it has to be based on the context of the relationship(field), not the class.

**i.e.** deserializer(ParentA.sameChild) <> deserializer(ParentB.sameChild)

### First try: @Annotations

```
class Parent {
   @Deserializer(using=MyIdDeserializer<Child>.class)
   public Child myChild;
}

class MyIdDeserializer<T extends ChildDAO> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {
   public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        Integer id = node.get("id").asInt();
        return T.find(id);
   }
}
```

**Question 1:** Any idea how to pass the *class Child* to the scope of the method *T deserialize()*?

**Question 2:** Is there any other strategy to solve this?

---

### Example of my generic "Serializer"

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonSimpleName.SimpleNameSerializer.class)
public @interface JsonSimpleName {

    public static class SimpleNameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JsonSimpleNameI> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(JsonSimpleNameI value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.jsonId());
            jgen.writeStringField("name", value.jsonName());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}

public interface JsonSimpleNameI {
    public Integer  jsonId();
    public String   jsonName();
}
```

Now I can use a simple annotation in classes that implement `JsonSimpleNameI`:

```
@JsonSimpleName
protected MyClass myClass;
```

Comment: Similar question, but I would not like to add this info into the json object:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937197/how-to-define-a-generic-list-deserializer-through-annotations-with-jackson

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a similar problem with using a generic deserializer at the field level.

Comment: @mpprdev nope... =/