# Jackson deserialize convert the null list to empty list without initializing

Tags: java, jackson

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = JacksonTest.JacksonTestBuilder.class)
public class JacksonTest {

    private final String id;

    private final String name;

    private List<String> hobbies;

    private List<CustomType> customs;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class JacksonTestBuilder {
    }

}
```

I have json

```
{"id":"id"}
```

**Expected pojo will have**

```
 id: id
 name: null
 hobbies : empty lists
 customs: empty list
```

How can we deserialize null lists/collection as empty collection with out explicitely initializing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom deserializer should work.

Have a look at this question:

[How to define a generic list deserializer through annotations with Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937197/how-to-define-a-generic-list-deserializer-through-annotations-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

depends what you mean by explicitly initializing the variable - someone eventually needs to do it; one easy option is to use `@Builder.Default`

```
@Getter
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class JacksonTest {

    private final String id;

    private final String name;
    @Builder.Default
    private List<String> hobbies = List.of();
    @Builder.Default
    private List<CustomType> customs = List.of();


}
```

this allows the builder to use the default value when no other value is received from the json file and rather relies on lombok for initialization and not jackson.